# Cannot compile after manually update a package

Tags: xetex, updating, xepersian

I decide to manually update a package {because of freezing texlive 2015} (xepersian-from 16.1 to 16.5)

I follow these steps:

1. Download zip file from ctan
2. Extract
3. generate .sty by running cmd:

[image]

4. Copy and replace all generated files in C:\localtexmf\xepersian & C:\texlive\2015\texmf-dist\tex\xelatex\xepersian (My TeXlive is installed in C:Texlive)
5. Texhash in cmd

[image]
Done

Now I expecting texlive identify new version, but not only newer version dont configure but also files can not be compiled.

Now by running cmd I got this massage:

[image] 
that shows texlive can not understand new version

Comment: Manually installing a new version of a package into an existing TL tree can cause troubles -- it might work, but there is no guarantee. In my opinion, switching to TL 2016 is the better option here.

Comment: `tlmgr info` will show the old version as you have not updated via texlive so its metadata is unchanged but latex will see the new version that you have placed in the same position. So your tlmgr output is not really very relevant, do you get an error _from latex_ ?

Comment: No error! But not compile.

Comment: @hosseinbehboodi it is impossible to help if you give no clues, post a small sample document and the result of running  pdflatex on it. If the file is called `abc.tex` and you type `pdflatex abc` it can not "not compile" you must either get some output or an error from tex or the operating system.

Comment: tlmgr doesn't look in the files to get the version of a package, it has its own database. If you manually exchange files (or put a newer version in texmf-local) tlmgr will not know about it. Why your files no longer compile is unclear, but it is quite possible that the newer xepersion is not compatible with the older latex or some older package in TL2015.